# Not getting location from map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am making location based reminder app...but when i click on specific location then marker add to this location but when i click on submit it not show the selected location..it is getting only my current longitude and latitude...here is my code....

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_to_map);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    this.mainClass = (MainClass) getApplication();
    this.drawablered = getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.mainpin);
    final Drawable buttonSelector = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.buttonselector);
    this.buttonSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
    this.buttonShowSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonShowSearch);

    this.locationTextView = new AutoCompleteTextView(getApplicationContext());
    this.buttonSearch = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    this.width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    density = displaymetrics.densityDpi;
    this.locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean available = false;
    NetworkInfo netInfo = ((ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        available = true;
    }
    if (!available) {
        this.mainClass.setLongToast("Sorry, there is not network connection to display the map");
    }
    try {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            int hasReadContactPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            if (hasReadContactPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        124);
                return;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
    if (this.locationManager != null) {
        this.currentLocation = this.locationManager.getLastKnownLocation("gps");
        if (this.currentLocation != null) {
            this.currentLatitude = Double.valueOf(this.currentLocation.getLatitude());
            this.currentLongitude = Double.valueOf(this.currentLocation.getLongitude());
            this.currentPoint = new LatLng((int) (this.currentLatitude.doubleValue() * 1000000.0d), (int) (this.currentLongitude.doubleValue() * 1000000.0d));
            locationLat = this.currentLatitude.doubleValue();
            locationLong = this.currentLongitude.doubleValue();
        } else {

        }
    } else {

    }

    this.buttonShowSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AddLocationActivity.this.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) AddLocationActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.layout_search);
            AddLocationActivity.this.locationTextView.setHint("Location to search");
            //AddLocationActivity.this.locationTextView.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            AddLocationActivity.this.locationTextView.setWidth((AddLocationActivity.this.width / 4) * 3);
            AddLocationActivity.this.locationTextView.setHeight(36);
            AddLocationActivity.this.buttonSearch.setWidth(AddLocationActivity.this.width * 0);
            AddLocationActivity.this.buttonSearch.setHeight(40);
            AddLocationActivity.this.buttonSearch.setBackgroundDrawable(buttonSelector);
            AddLocationActivity.this.buttonSearch.setText("Search");
            AddLocationActivity.this.buttonSearch.setTextColor(-1);
            AddLocationActivity.this.linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            AddLocationActivity.this.linearLayout.setVerticalGravity(16);
            AddLocationActivity.this.linearLayout.addView(AddLocationActivity.this.locationTextView);
            AddLocationActivity.this.linearLayout.addView(AddLocationActivity.this.buttonSearch);
            AddLocationActivity.this.buttonShowSearch.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    this.buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AddLocationActivity.this.location = AddLocationActivity.this.locationTextView.getText().toString();
            AddLocationActivity.this.location.trim();
            if (AddLocationActivity.this.location.compareTo("") != 0) {
                AddLocationActivity.this.searchLocation();
                AddLocationActivity.this.linearLayout.removeAllViews();
                return;
            }
            AddLocationActivity.this.mainClass.setLongToast("Please enter a location");
        }
    });
    this.buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (AddLocationActivity.locationLat == 0.0d || AddLocationActivity.locationLong == 0.0d) {
                AddLocationActivity.this.mainClass.setLongToast("Sorry, failed to submit");
                return;
            }
            AddLocationActivity.this.mainClass.latitude = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(AddLocationActivity.locationLat)).toString();
            AddLocationActivity.this.mainClass.longitude = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(AddLocationActivity.locationLong)).toString();
            AddLocationActivity.this.mainClass.locationName = AddLocationActivity.locationName;
            AddLocationActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
}


protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    this.mainClass.favListFlag = false;

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return this.mainClass.menuItemClick(item, getBaseContext());
}

protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

private void searchLocation() {
    final Handler Modelhandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            AddLocationActivity.this.buttonShowSearch.setEnabled(true);
            if (msg.obj == "1") {
                AddLocationActivity.this.locationTextView.setText("");
                AddLocationActivity.this.mainClass.setLongToast("Sorry, this location could not be marked, please mark the point manually");
            } else if (msg.obj == "2") {
                AddLocationActivity.this.addMarker(AddLocationActivity.this.point, AddLocationActivity.locationName);
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder;
            Message msg = new Message();
            try {
                ((InputMethodManager) AddLocationActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(AddLocationActivity.this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            String str = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < AddLocationActivity.this.location.length(); i++) {
                if (AddLocationActivity.this.location.substring(i, i + 1).equalsIgnoreCase(" ")) {
                    str = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(str)).append("+").toString();
                } else {
                    str = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(str)).append(AddLocationActivity.this.location.substring(i, i + 1)).toString();
                }
            }
            if (str.compareTo("") != 0) {
                AddLocationActivity.this.location = str;
            }

            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            String responseStr = "";
            try {


                url = new URL("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + AddLocationActivity.this.location + "ka&sensor=false");

                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(false);

                DataOutputStream wr = new
                        DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
                // Get Response
                int status = connection.getResponseCode();
                BufferedInputStream in;
                if (status >= 400) {
                    in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getErrorStream());
                } else {
                    in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                }

                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                    response.append('\r');
                }
                rd.close();
                responseStr = response.toString();
                Log.d("Server response", responseStr);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();


            } finally {

                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }

            }


            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseStr);
            } catch (JSONException e4) {
                e4.printStackTrace();
            }
            Double d = new Double(0.0d);
            d = new Double(0.0d);
            Double lon1 = 0.0, lat1 = 0.0;
            try {
                lon1 = Double.valueOf(((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lng"));
                lat1 = Double.valueOf(((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lat"));
            } catch (JSONException e42) {
                e42.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (lon1.doubleValue() == 0.0d && lat1.doubleValue() == 0.0d) {
                msg.obj = "1";
            } else {
                AddLocationActivity.this.point = new LatLng((int) (lat1.doubleValue() * 1000000.0d), (int) (lon1.doubleValue() * 1000000.0d));
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(AddLocationActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                    StringBuilder _homeAddress = new StringBuilder();
                    try {
                        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat1.doubleValue(), lon1.doubleValue(), 1);
                        for (int index = 0; index < addresses.size(); index++) {
                            Address address = (Address) addresses.get(index);
                            AddLocationActivity.locationLat = lat1.doubleValue();
                            AddLocationActivity.locationLong = lon1.doubleValue();
                            if (address.getLocality() == null) {
                                AddLocationActivity.locationName = address.getAddressLine(0);
                            } else {
                                AddLocationActivity.locationName = address.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.getLocality();
                            }
                        }
                        stringBuilder = _homeAddress;
                    } catch (Exception e5) {
                        stringBuilder = _homeAddress;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e6) {
                }
                msg.obj = "2";
            }
            Modelhandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }.start();
}

private void addMarker(LatLng point, String locationName) {
    if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.clear();
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));

        this.itemizedoverlay = new MapItemizedOverlay(this.drawablered, getApplicationContext());

        this.itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(this.overlayitem);
        this.mapOverlays.add(this.itemizedoverlay);
        this.mv.invalidate();
        if (!locationName.equals("")) {
            View map_popup = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.map_popup, null);
            ((TextView) map_popup.findViewById(R.id.textViewLocName)).setText(locationName);
            this.mainClass.toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            this.mainClass.toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            this.mainClass.toast.setGravity(48, 0, ((height / 2) - (height / 10)) - 60);
            this.mainClass.toast.setView(map_popup);
            this.mainClass.toast.show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    //this.mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34.0d, 151.0d);
    this.mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Sydney"));
    this.mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 10.0f));
    this.mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            AddLocationActivity.this.mMap.clear();
            AddLocationActivity.locationLat = latLng.latitude;
            AddLocationActivity.locationLong = latLng.longitude;
            AddLocationActivity.this.mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(AddLocationActivity.locationLat, AddLocationActivity.locationLong)).title(BuildConfig.FLAVOR + AddLocationActivity.locationLat + "\n" + AddLocationActivity.locationLong));
            AddLocationActivity.this.mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(AddLocationActivity.locationLat, AddLocationActivity.locationLong), 10.9f));

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: I am not what you are trying to do, but what i think is that when you say 'requestLocationUpdates', it updates the location to current location. Test it again with not requesting location updates.